# Sort multiple columns with specific characteristics in a csv file using c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have to sort multiple columns in a csv file.
A part of my file is like this:

```
Number | Section | Color | Length | Panel1 | Panel2 | Description
1          1.5      BK      200     PAN5A    PAN5B     ABC
2          0.75     BK      620     PAN3A    PAN3A     ACC
3          2        RD      150     PAN2A    PAN2A     AAA
4          1.5      BL      500     PAN2A    PAN2A     ABB
5          0.75     GY      250     PAN1A    PAN2A     AAA
6          5.25     GY      200     PAN3A    PAN3B     CCC
7          1.25     BU      150     PAN4A    PAN4A     DDD
8          0.75     BK      800     PAN4A    PAN4A     BBB
```

I have to order column 3 (Color) in a specific order. The order I have to follow is the following (GY, BL, RD, other colors, BK), are the acronyms of the colors.
I must then order for column 2 (Section) this by number, for column 4 (length) also by number.

The goal would be to have the following csv file.

```
Number | Section | Color | Length | Panel1 | Panel2 | Description
5          0.75     GY      250     PAN1A    PAN2A     AAA
6          5.25     GY      200     PAN3A    PAN3B     CCC
4          1.5      BL      500     PAN2A    PAN2A     ABB
3          2        RD      150     PAN2A    PAN2A     AAA
7          1.25     BU      150     PAN4A    PAN4A     DDD`
2          0.75     BK      620     PAN3A    PAN3A     ACC
8          0.75     BK      800     PAN4A    PAN4A     BBB  
1          1.5      BK      200     PAN5A    PAN5B     ABC
```

Below I put my code but it has problems. Because column 3 orders it alphabetically, columns 2 and 4 see the numbers as strings and therefore do not follow the correct order.

```
var sorted = File.ReadLines(pathFile)
            .Select(line => new
            {
                SortKeyColor = line.Split(';')[2],
                SortKeySection = line.Split(';')[1],
                SortKeyLenght = line.Split(';')[3],
                Line = line
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.SortKeyColor)
            .ThenBy(x => x.SortKeySection)
            .ThenBy(x => x.SortKeyLenght)
            .Select(x => x.Line);

            File.WriteAllLines(pathNewFile, sorted);
```

I also tried to put Int32.Parse but I get the exception "Input string format incorrect."

```
SortKeySection = Int32.Parse(line.Split(';')[1]),
```

Comment: Sorry I put int32 in column 3 and double.parse in column 1, but still gives me the error

Comment: Then, column 2 (SortKeyColor) is a string; column 1 (SortKeySection) is a comma number while column 3 (SortKeyLength) is an integer. Was this what you asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the value of "SortKeyColor" by a temporary int value for sorting:

```
         // Converting string to integers with the desired order
         Func<string, int> converter = (color) =>
         {
             switch (color)
             {
                 case "GY": return 0;
                 case "BL": return 1;
                 case "RD": return 2;
                 case "BK": return 4;
                 default: return 3;
             }
         };

        var sorted = File.ReadLines("")
        .Select(line => new
        {
            SortKeyColor = converter(line.Split(';')[2]),
            SortKeySection = double.Parse(line.Split(';')[1]),
            SortKeyLenght = int.Parse(line.Split(';')[3]),
            Line = line
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortKeyColor)
        .ThenBy(x => x.SortKeySection)
        .ThenBy(x => x.SortKeyLenght)
        .Select(x => x.Line);
```

Edit: I added conversion methods.

Answer (score 0):

You get the format exception because Column 1 (actually the second column) is not an integer. This should work:

```
.ThenBy(x => double.Parse(x.SortKeySection))
.ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.SortKeyLenght))
```

But it would be better (and faster) to adjust the types of `SortKeySection` and `SortKeyLength` and assign the correct datatype:

```
SortKeySection = double.Parse(line.Split(';')[1]),
SortKeyLenght = int.Parse(line.Split(';')[3]),
```

Depending on your locale, you might want to add a specific culture, e.g.:

```
double.Parse(line.Split(';')[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

In case your local number format has a different decimal separator like `,` or `;`.

---

For the proper order of your colors, you might want to use a custom `IComparer<string>` that gives you better control over which element should come before the other. This implementation for example sorts `GY`, `BL` and `RD` first, then everything else in alphabetical order and then all `BK`:

```
public class ColorNameComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly List<string> colorOrder = new List<string>{"GY", "BL", "RD"};
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;

        if (x == "BK") return 1;
        if (y == "BK") return -1;

        if (colorOrder.Contains(x) && colorOrder.Contains(y))
            return colorOrder.IndexOf(x) > colorOrder.IndexOf(y) ? 1 : -1;
        if (colorOrder.Contains(x))
            return -1;
        if (colorOrder.Contains(y))
            return 1;

        return String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.SortKeyColor, new ColorNameComparer())
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string file =
                "1;1.5;BK;200;PAN5A;PAN5B;ABC\r\n" +
                "2;0.75;BK;620;PAN3A;PAN3A;ACC\r\n" +
                "3;2;RD;150;PAN2A;PAN2A;AAA\r\n" +
                "4;1.5;BL;500;PAN2A;PAN2A;ABB\r\n" +
                "5;0.75;GY;250;PAN1A;PAN2A;AAA\r\n" +
                "6;5.25;GY;200;PAN3A;PAN3B;CCC\r\n" +
                "7;1.25;BU;150;PAN4A;PAN4A;DDD\r\n" +
                "8;0.75;BK;800;PAN4A;PAN4A;BBB";
            string[] lines = file.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var sorted = lines.Select(line => new
                {
                    SortKeyColor = line.Split(';')[2],
                    SortKeySection = double.Parse(line.Split(';')[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    SortKeyLenght = int.Parse(line.Split(';')[3]),
                    Line = line
                }

            ).OrderBy(x => x.SortKeyColor, new ColorNameComparer()).ThenBy(x => x.SortKeySection).ThenBy(x => x.SortKeyLenght).Select(x => x.Line);
            foreach (var entry in sorted)
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
    }

    public class ColorNameComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        private readonly List<string> colorOrder = new List<string> {"GY", "BL", "RD"};

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == y)
                return 0;
            if (x == "BK")
                return 1;
            if (y == "BK")
                return -1;
            if (colorOrder.Contains(x) && colorOrder.Contains(y))
                return colorOrder.IndexOf(x) > colorOrder.IndexOf(y) ? 1 : -1;
            if (colorOrder.Contains(x))
                return -1;
            if (colorOrder.Contains(y))
                return 1;
            return String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implement custom comparer

```
    public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> colorPriorities;
        public CustomComparer()
        {
            colorPriorities = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            colorPriorities.Add("GY", 1);
            colorPriorities.Add("BL", 2);
            colorPriorities.Add("RD", 4);
            colorPriorities.Add("BK", 8);
        }
        public int GetPriority(string color)
        {
            if (!colorPriorities.ContainsKey(color))
            {
                return 5;
            }

            return colorPriorities[color];
        }
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            string xSortKeyColor = x.Split(';')[2];
            double xSortKeySection = Convert.ToDouble(x.Split(';')[1]);
            double xSortKeyLenght = Convert.ToDouble(x.Split(';')[3]);

            string ySortKeyColor = y.Split(';')[2];
            double ySortKeySection = Convert.ToDouble(y.Split(';')[1]);
            double ySortKeyLenght = Convert.ToDouble(y.Split(';')[3]);

            if (xSortKeyColor != ySortKeyColor)
                return GetPriority(xSortKeyColor).CompareTo(GetPriority(ySortKeyColor));

            if (xSortKeySection != ySortKeySection)
                return xSortKeySection.CompareTo(ySortKeySection);

            return xSortKeyLenght.CompareTo(ySortKeyLenght);
        }
    }
```